# Using epel in RHEL 7 behind proxy

Tags: linux, proxy, redhat-enterprise-linux, yum

I am running Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server 7, and I am having some problems getting the Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux (epel) repo to behave (ultimately I want to install XFCE). I think I have identified the problem to be my corporate proxy settings.

I have installed epel by

```
wget http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/7Server/x86_64/e/epel-release-7-9.noarch.rpm
sudo rpm -ivh epel-release-7-9.noarch.rpm
```

This went fine (I have configured my ~/.wgetrc file to use my proxy settings). However, when I try to do

```
sudo yum repolist
```

I get an error: "cannot retrieve metalink for repository: epel/x86_64. Please verify its path and try again" whereas a

```
sudo yum --disablerepo=epel repolist
```

works fine. Running

```
URLGRABBER_DEBUG=1 yum repolist
```

lead me to believe that it is a proxy issue due to the following extract:

```
2017-01-13 17:23:18,207 attempt 1/10: https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=epel-7&arch=x86_64
2017-01-13 17:23:18,207 opening local file "/var/tmp/yum-usernameredacted-nARLQn/x86_64/7Server/epel/metalink.xml.tmp" with mode wb
* About to connect() to mirrors.fedoraproject.org port 443 (#10)
*   Trying 209.132.181.15...
* After 14938ms connect time, move on!
*   Trying 152.19.134.142...
* After 7468ms connect time, move on!
*   Trying 209.132.181.16...
* After 3734ms connect time, move on!
*   Trying 185.141.165.254...
* After 1866ms connect time, move on!
*   Trying 174.141.234.172...
* After 932ms connect time, move on!
*   Trying 152.19.134.198...
* After 466ms connect time, move on!
*   Trying 67.219.144.68...
* After 232ms connect time, move on!
*   Trying 8.43.85.67...
* After 116ms connect time, move on!
*   Trying 140.211.169.206...
* After 58ms connect time, move on!
*   Trying 140.211.169.196...
* After 28ms connect time, move on!
*   Trying 2604:1580:fe00:0:dead:beef:cafe:fed1...
* Failed to connect to 2604:1580:fe00:0:dead:beef:cafe:fed1: Network is unreachable
*   Trying 2610:28:3090:3001:dead:beef:cafe:fed3...
* Failed to connect to 2610:28:3090:3001:dead:beef:cafe:fed3: Network is unreachable
*   Trying 2605:bc80:3010:600:dead:beef:cafe:fed9...
* Failed to connect to 2605:bc80:3010:600:dead:beef:cafe:fed9: Network is unreachable
* Failed connect to mirrors.fedoraproject.org:443; Network is unreachable
* Closing connection 10
2017-01-13 17:23:48,178 exception: [Errno 14] curl#7 - "Failed to connect to 2604:1580:fe00:0:dead:beef:cafe:fed1: Network is unreachable"
2017-01-13 17:23:48,178 retrycode (14) not in list [-1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7], re-raising
```

I have sudo rights, but I cannot access most yum configurations. What is a plausible solution?

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you need to provide your proxy details to `yum` so that you can connect;

In `/etc/yum.conf` you should add the following lines (updated with your valid proxy & login details).

```
proxy=http://<your proxy address>:<proxy port>
proxy_username=<username>
proxy_password=<password>
```

This is *obviously* a security concern as you will have valid login credentials in plain text in your config file. Anyone looking will be able to take those details so ensure you know your security arrangements.

More info can be found in the docs [here](https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/yum/sn-yum-proxy-server.html).

If your unable to add this to the `yum.conf` your only real option is to contact someone who can, anything more would involve setting up more proxys and forwarders which I suspect you can't do anyway.

Comment: immediate fix to this nagging problem.  Thank you.